# JS file not being found in .NET visual studio using Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, html, .net, razor, blazor

I am trying to add a JS script file called `chatfunction.js` into my `index.html` in Blazor but it gives me an error that it cannot find a file. My CSS is linked correctly and the HTML and CSS both show up but it does not provide any of the JS functionality that I have implemented.

I am adding it at the bottom of my HTML in `index.html` like this:

```
....
 <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="chatfunction.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my project structure

[image]
Now when I try compiling it gives me this error:

```
(JS) File 'C:/Users/darka/source/repos/chatproject/wwwroot/js/mysrc.js' not found.
```

I don't get why it can't find it and I am confused as to why it thinks my file is mysrc.js as there is no file like that in my project structure.

Any pointers how to fix this?

Here is the layout of my JS file

```
var botController = (function () {


})();

var uiController = (function () {


})();




var controller = (function (botCntr, uiCntr) {
    var $chatCircle,
        $chatBox,
        $chatBoxClose,
        $chatBoxWelcome,
        $chatWraper,
        $submitBtn,
        $chatInput,
        $msg;

    /*toggle*/
    function hideCircle(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $chatCircle.hide('scale');
        $chatBox.show('scale');
        $chatBoxWelcome.show('scale');
    }

    function chatBoxCl(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $chatCircle.show('scale');
        $chatBox.hide('scale');
        $chatBoxWelcome.hide('scale');
        $chatWraper.hide('scale');
    }

    function chatOpenMessage(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $chatBoxWelcome.hide();
        $chatWraper.show();
    }

    //generate messages on submit click
    function submitMsg(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        //1. get input message data
        msg = $chatSubmitBtn.val();

        //2.if there is no string button send shoudn't work
        if (msg.trim() == '') {
            return false;
        }
        //3. add message to bot controller
        callbot(msg);
        //4. display message to ui controller
        generate_message(msg, 'self');

    }

    function chatSbmBtn(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13 || evt.which === 13) {
            console.log("btn pushed");
        }
    }
    /* var input = uiCntr.getInput();*/
    /* $chatSubmitBtn.on("click", hideCircle);*/



    function init() {
        $chatCircle = $("#chat-circle");
        $chatBox = $(".chat-box");
        $chatBoxClose = $(".chat-box-toggle");
        $chatBoxWelcome = $(".chat-box-welcome__header");
        $chatWraper = $("#chat-box__wraper");
        $chatInput = $("#chat-input__text");
        $submitBtn = $("#chat-submit");

        //1. call toggle 
        $chatCircle.on("click", hideCircle);
        $chatBoxClose.on("click", chatBoxCl);
        $chatInput.on("click", chatOpenMessage);

        //2. call wait message from CRM-human

        $submitBtn.on("click", chatSbmBtn);
        $chatInput.on("keypress", chatSbmBtn);


        //6. get message from bot controller-back end
        //7. display bot message to ui controller
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };

})(botController, uiController);


$('.chat-input__form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    msg = $('.chat-input__text').val();

    $('.chat-logs').append('<div id="cm-msg-0" class="chat-msg background-warning push-right bot"><div class="cm-msg-text">' + msg + '</div><span class="msg-avatar"><img class="chat-box-overlay_robot" src="https://www.meetsource.com//userStyles/images/user.png"></span></div>');
    $('.chat-input__text').val('');
});


$(document).ready(controller.init);


function talk() {
    var user = document.getElementById("userBox").value;
    document.getElementById("userBox").value = "";
    document.getElementById("chatLog").innerHTML += user + "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it inside of `<head></head>` instead of `<body></body>`:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/chatfunction.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also specify the right path.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your script line needs to be:

```
<script src="js/chatfunction.js"></script>
```